# Recursive/Hierarchical Query in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, hierarchical-data

Scenario is,

im using EntityFrame Work 6. I have a DB have table having structure below.

```
cat_id     geo_id     parent_id geo_name
   Root       1       NULL      Pakistan
   Province   2        1        Punjab
   District   3        2        Attock
   City       4        3        Attock
   City       5        3        Fateh Jang
   City       6        3        Hasan Abdal
```

Table have hierarchical data in relational form,as you can see.

I want to traverse this hierarchy, want to specific parent level, If im at `geo_id 6` then I want to go `parent_id 3` and get value `Attock` or want to go to `parent_id 2` and want to get value `Punjab`.

Moral of the story is,standing at any child,want traverse till specified parent or grand parent,not entire hierarchy. Below is code I have tried but it gives me only its immediate parent.

More Shortly, Want a LINQ query,which will return name of specified parent or grand parent,For Example. I can ask my query, "hey! im `Hasan Abdal(City)`,tell me my `Province`"

```
Province = (from cp in db.geo_hierarchy
                                                     join mp in db.geo_hierarchy on cp.parent_id equals mp.geo_id
                                                     where cp.geo_name == risk.geo_hierarchy.geo_name 
                                                     select mp.geo_name).FirstOrDefault()
```

see full code below,it used in inside LINQ query's `select` clause

```
 Risklists = (from risk in db.risk_cat_detail
            where risk.occurance_date.Value.Year==2014 && risk.occurance_date.Value.Month>=6 && risk.occurance_date.Value.Month<=9
                                 select new risk_cat_detail_contract()
                                 {
                                     cat_id = risk.cat_id,
                                     catdesc = risk.category_main.cat_name,
                                     risk_cat_detail_id = risk.risk_cat_detail_id,
                                     trans_date = risk.trans_date.Value,
                                     occurance_date = risk.occurance_date.Value,
                                     occurance_time = risk.occurance_time,

                                     geo_id = risk.geo_id,
                                     geo_desc = risk.geo_hierarchy.geo_name,
                                     Province = (from cp in db.geo_hierarchy
                                                 join mp in db.geo_hierarchy on cp.parent_id equals mp.geo_id
                                                 where cp.geo_name == risk.geo_hierarchy.geo_name 
                                                 select mp.geo_name).FirstOrDefault()







                                 }).ToList<risk_cat_detail_contract>();
```

Help me out,Thanks in Advance

Comment: How should we determine what the specific parent is?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you let us know what the criteria is to stop moving up from the current node?

Comment: I Updated my table again,Inserted Values of cat_ids. I want to traverse upward. if im at city then may want to go to its District or Province, or Country (Root).Want a LINQ query,which will return name of specified parent or grand parent,FOr Example. I can ask my query, "hey! im Hasan Abdal(City),tell me my province"

Comment: @Enigmativity, Hope you got me now

Comment: When doing a simple recursion like this I use a common table expression. If you don't know what that is then searching for SQL CTE should give you plenty of results. What you would do is create a view which uses a CTE then map an entity to that view.

Comment: @AndyNichols is it not possible in LINQ directly? if not then explain your method more please.im newbie to CTE

Comment: @ZaidMirza - Please don't just delete comments like that. It makes it hard to understand the sequence of the comments.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I deleted beacuse it will confuse the reader as I changed my termonology of levels ,instead of root,branch,leaf, im using now city,district,province,root(Country), Sorry. I did it so that you may understand my issue properly

Comment: @ZaidMirza - Readers can always look at the change history for the question. They can't do that for comments. It's almost always better to leave them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var geo_hierarchy = new []
{
    new { cat_id = "Root", geo_id = 1, parent_id = (int?)null, geo_name = "Pakistan", },
    new { cat_id = "Province", geo_id = 2, parent_id = (int?)1, geo_name = "Punjab", },
    new { cat_id = "District", geo_id = 3, parent_id = (int?)2, geo_name = "Attock", },
    new { cat_id = "City", geo_id = 4, parent_id = (int?)3, geo_name = "Attock", },
    new { cat_id = "City", geo_id = 5, parent_id = (int?)3, geo_name = "Fateh Jang", },
    new { cat_id = "City", geo_id = 6, parent_id = (int?)3, geo_name = "Hasan Abdal", },
};

var map = geo_hierarchy.ToDictionary(x => x.geo_id);

Func<int, string, string> up = null;
up = (geo_id, cat_id) =>
{
    var record = map[geo_id];
    return
        record.cat_id == cat_id
            ? record.geo_name
            : (record.parent_id.HasValue
                ? up(record.parent_id.Value, cat_id)
                : null);
};

var result = up(5, "Province"); // -> "Punjab"
```

Comment: can i call this function? inside a LINQ's `select` clause to assign value to my variable named `Province`, as you can see my post. im getting province inside a LINQ's `select`

Comment: @ZaidMirza - No, you'd have to do this outside of the select.

Comment: I have thousands of objects.  will it may cause performance issue?

Comment: @ZaidMirza - No. Probably not. If you could include this in your query then you would probably have a very big performance issue. But running this outside of your query should make it very fast indeed.

Comment: @ZaidMirza - Is it fast enough?